# Задача по информатике(теория информации)

Tags: информатика

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решать вот такую вот задачу. 
Сколько можно построить различных последовательностей, состоящих не менее чем из 3 и не более чем из 6 четверичных знаков?(Например, из 0,1,2,3)

Answer (score 4):

Я бы данную задачу решил так:

- Возможные наборы чисел: xxx, xxxx, xxxxx, xxxxxx
- Система счисления четверичная, соответственно, вместо x будем подставлять число 4.

Далее перемножаем основание системы счисления на количество знаков и складываем между собой:

(4 * 4 * 4) + (4 * 4 * 4 * 4) + (4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4) + (4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4) = 64 * (1 + 4 + 16 + 64) = 5440

По-хорошему, надо в комбинаторику заглянуть, там это более обобщённо описано.

Comment: Все верно. В терминах комбинаторики это называется [**размещениями с повторениями**][1].


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.89.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.B2.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F.D0.BC.D0.B8

Comment: @Shad, Спасибо, теперь буду знать к какому разделу комбинаторики обращаться, а то ведь искал и не нашёл.